# Simple Lisp Case statement question - problem comparing to nil

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, case-statement

I'm trying to use a case statement to make some code more readable.  It seems to work as a series of if statements, but for some reason the case statement always accepts a comparison to nil even if it is not true.  Can someone clarify why this behavior occurs?

Example:

```
> (case 'a            
    (nil nil)         
    (otherwise 'b))   
NIL                   
> (case 'a            
    ('a 'b)           
    (otherwise nil))  
B
```

In the above example, the first instance returns nil, even though 'a clearly is not nil.  Trying to do the same thing with if statements behaves as I would expect:

```
> (if (eq 'a nil) nil 'b)    
B                            
> (if (eq 'a 'a) 'b nil)     
B
```

I'm assuming there is some behavior about the case statement I do not understand.  Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Just to clarify, I know that 'a won't be evaluated.  I just mocked up this example to create a situation in which the target of the case statement was definitely NOT nil.

I'm using xlisp-plus, but I'm going to try a real clisp install and see if it behaves differently.

Edit (one more time):
Installed CLISP and it works fine there.  Not really worth the trouble to investigate why xlisp is different.  Thanks for the sanity check, everyone.

Comment: That's strange. I just tried your first case expression in GNU Common Lisp 2.6.7 and (as expected) it evaluates to B.

Comment: "xlisp" is an important bit of information, from the [web page](http://www.xlisp.org/): "XLISP 3.0 is a superset of the **Scheme** dialect of Lisp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that it depends on your LISP version. 
I have LispWorks on Mac and my result :

```
CL-USER 2 : 1 > (case 'a            
    (nil nil)         
    (otherwise 'b))   
B
```

Answer (score 4):

Each of the key specifications in a `CASE` may be either a list of literals or a single atom.  However, [CLtL says that the atom must not be `NIL`](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node84.html) since it is ambiguous as to whether it is the literal `NIL` or an empty list.  Use a list of `NIL` instead:

```
> (case 'a
    ((nil) nil)         
    (otherwise 'b))
B
> (case nil
    ((nil) nil)         
    (otherwise 'b))
NIL
```

Comment: In an impressive display of uselessness, xlisp manages to fail even that method of formatting the problem.

Comment: XLISP is not a Common Lisp dialect.  I guess there's always `COND` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Common Lisp expects for CASE the item to test to be an atom or a list of atoms. The test also is the function EQL.

```
(case 'a
  (a 'b)    ; EQL a
  (otherwise 'foo))

(case 'a
  ((a b c) 'foo)   ; EQL to one of a, b or c
  (otherwise 'bar))
```

The quoted for only works by accident. Don't use it:

```
; don't use this:
(case 'a
  ('a 'foo)    ; <- bad!  , EQL to QUOTE or A
  (otherwise 'bar))
```

Above is the same as:

```
; don't use this:
(case 'a
  ((quote a) 'foo)   ; <- bad! ,  EQL to QUOTE or A
  (otherwise 'bar))
```

Answer (score 1):

Same here with SBCL:

```
CL-USER> (case 'a
           (nil nil)
           (otherwise 'b))
B
```

That said, `'a` is a *symbol* and as such can never be `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

The values in a [`case`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_case_.htm) form are implicitly quoted lists of literals, so this:

```
(case 'a
  ((a) 'b)
  (otherwise nil))
```

is what you want.  `otherwise` should work (as others have said) -- try `t` instead.

BTW, when you used `'a` the reader reads it as `(quote a)` which means that it will also choose it when the value is `quote`, for example:

```
(case 'quote
  ('a 'b)
  (otherwise nil))
```